# Find angle of rotation, inverted y axis, between two points in 2D

Tags: graphics, trigonometry, eigen3, coordinate-systems

Background :
I am implementing an application where I need to do affine transformations on a selected line. Line is represented using 2 points. All the code is done in mouse events.

```
void mousePressEvent(){
    lastPoint = event.point();
}
void mouseMoveEvent(){
    currentPoint = event.point();

    //Do transformations here.

    translate_factor = currentPoint - lastPoint
    scale_factor = currentPoint / lastPoint

    rotation_angle = f(current_point,last_point) //FIND f

    //Apply transformation
    lastPoint = currentPoint
}
```

I have two points, `p1` and `p2`. The X axis increases from left to right. Y axis increases top to bottom. I have a point `d` around which I want to rotate a set of points `p_set` .
How do I find the angle of rotation from `p1` to `p2` about `d` .

What I am doing is translate `p1` , `p2` by `-d` and calculate theta by using `atan2f` as shown in the following code.

Note that y is inverted : goes from top to bottom.
Here is the code

```
const auto about = stroke->getMidPoint();
Eigen::Affine2f t1(Eigen::Translation2f(0-about.x(),0-about.y()));

Eigen::Vector3f p1 = t1.matrix()*Eigen::Vector3f(lastPoint.x(),lastPoint.y(),1.0);
Eigen::Vector3f p2 = t1.matrix()*Eigen::Vector3f(currentPoint.x(),currentPoint.y(),1.0);

float theta = atan2f(p2[1]-p1[1],p2[0]-p1[0]);
```

When I transform using this, I get very weird rotations.
What I want is to find angle as a function of current and last points

Comment: Sounds like more of a trigonometry question than a C++ question...

Comment: Do you care about the direction of rotation? You could go either way, or multiple turns. Is this important?

Comment: @PeteBlackerThe3rd I have added background on where I need this. Yes, they matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're finding the slope of the vector `p2-p1`.
If I understood correctly, you want the difference of the slopes of the two vectors `p2-d` and `p1-d`, so the rotation angle is something like `atan((p2.y-d.y)/(p2.x-d.x)) - atan((p1.y-d.y)/(p1.x-d.x))`

Comment: Yup. Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Position {
    x: number
    y: number
}

const sub = (a: Position, b: Position): Position => {
    return { x: a.x - b.x, y: a.y - b.y }
}

const dot = (a: Position, b: Position): number => {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y
}

const cross = (a: Position, b: Position): number => {
    return a.x * b.y - b.x * a.y
}
const angleTo = (a: Position, b: Position): number => {
    return Math.atan2(cross(a, b), dot(a, b))
}

const oldVector = sub(p1, d) //Please note here
const nowVector = sub(p2, d) //Please note here

const rotate = angleTo(oldVector, nowVector)
```